# awk command line - remove line

Tags: awk

as per request posting code separate.

current output

```
Name,Final Grade,Section
Andrew is an online student
Andrew,95,online
Brandon is an online student
Brandon,100,online
Chelsey is an onsite student
Chelsey,100,onsite
Deborah is an online student
Deborah,72,online
Erik is an online student
Erik,65,online
Arielle is an onsite student
Arielle,88,onsite
Shaun is an onsite student
Shaun,91,onsite
Ninette is an online student
Ninette,82,online
Nguyen is an onsite student
Nguyen,80,onsite
```

output I'm supposed to achieve

```
Andrew is an online student
Brandon is an online student
Chelsey is an onsite student
Deborah is an online student
Erik is an online student
Arielle is an onsite student
Shaun is an onsite student
Ninette is an online student
Nguyen is an onsite student
```

basically, it's adding the line from the input file and not removing the header.
my issues is with removing it

```
  #!/usr/bin/awk -f
    ##comment create awk script that will output the given data in the format given in word document
    ##comment specify the delimiter as ","
    BEGIN { FS = "," }
    
    /./ {
    ##comment check if the third field is online, if print online
    if ($3 == "online")
    printf("%s is an online student\n", $1)
    
    ##commentcheck if the third field is onsite, if print onsite
    if ($3 == "onsite")
    printf("%s is an onsite student\n", $1)
    } $1
```

Comment: You posted actual and expected output but you forgot to post the input that you'd get that output from, We can't test a potential solution without sample input AND expected output. Don't use a shebang to call awk btw, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002754.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a shell script, `$1` refers to the first positional parameter (or argument) with which the script is called - you are probably used to using that to pass a filename to a [One-Shot Throwaway awk Program](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#One_002dshot)

Inside an [Executable awk Program](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Executable-Scripts) however, command line arguments are handled internally via awk's own `ARGV` array, and `$1` is the first field of the current record. Outside of a code block it is equivalent to

```
$1 != "" {
    print
}
```

which is therefore outputting every line of input that contains at least one non-`FS` character.

So remove the superfluous `$1`.